# elasticsearch geolocation rank

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I used `elasticsearch` client my query is above. I constantly get errors when sorting.

- query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "1km",
                    "location": { 40.2075448, 28.9992448 },
                    "unit": "km"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'from': params.page || 1,
    'size': params.size || 5,
}
```

- response

```json
{
    id: 203955,
    name: 'Crowne Plaza Bursa',
    location: [lat:40.210384,lon:28.998455],
},
{
    id: 204839,
    name: 'Sheraton Bursa Hotel',
    location: [lat:40.2074335,lon:28.9991297]
},
{ 
    id: 204838,
    name: 'Aloft Bursa',
    location: [lat:40.206863185056,lon:28.999087688955]
}
```

I need sorted near to far. I know `elasticsearch` has such support, but how to add it to my query.

Answer (score 0):

The [`geo_point` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html#geo-point) supports multiple formats but neither your docs nor your query fulfil it.

For the docs, go with lat/lon dictionaries instead of arrays:

```
{
  "id": 204839,
  "name": "Sheraton Bursa Hotel",
  "location": {              <---
    "lat": 40.2074335,
    "lon": 28.9991297
  }
}
```

Same principle applies for the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "1km",
          "location": {        <---
            "lat": 40.2075448,
            "lon": 28.9992448
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW -- no need for the `unit` parameter -- you specified the unit inside of the `distance` param.